# How to prevent Python's eval() from using "...", when evaluating lists?

Tags: python, eval

I've noticed that Python's *eval*() function shortens some lists, using "...":

```
In [10]: eval ('array([1. / 5.0e-12] + [0.]*1023)')
Out[10]: 
array([  2.00000000e+11,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
```

How can I prevent it from doing so?
(Subsequent code is barfing on the "...".):

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    initializer.channel_response = array([  2.00000000e+11,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is a typical "line" from one of my human-created configuration files:

```
('Pretap = 0', \
    ({'root_name'        : 'example_tx', \
      'tx_tap_np1'       : 0, \
      'tx_tap_nm1'       : 0, \
      'tx_tap_nm2'       : 0, \
     }, \
     {'channel_response' : array([1. / 5.0e-12] + [0.]*1023), \
      'sample_interval'  : 5.0e-12, \
     } \
    ) \
)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `eval`. You'd get the same result if you evaluated the same expression without `eval`. And the `...` is only present when displaying a numpy array as a string.

Comment: It looks like you're running `eval` on a string and then copying the result and pasting it into a different line of code. Why do that? Why not just do `initializer.channel_response = array([1. / 5.0e-12] + [0.]*1023)`?

Comment: Because, I'm reading several different configurations in from a file.

Comment: Comments don't support code blocks. If you want formatted text, you need to edit into your original post.

Comment: @Kevin, Thanks; original post updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to serialize (save) arrays in wrong way. Numpy has [np.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or [numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), which you can use to save data and later numpy.load or [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) it from file.

Don't use eval, it's neither safe nor sane to do this, because object representations may not show all information that is required to reliably reproduce some objects.

If you're loading human readable configuration, a common way is via module [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html).

Comment: okay, I get that; thanks! So, if I want to read in configuration information, from a human edited file, into a running Python script, what is the best way?

Comment: Commonly used is module configparser, some also use python modules directly and set constants there. Depends who will be changing these values.